# Admin Only Command Broken

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots, discord.js

So I've made an admin only command and it didn't go well. This codebin is the code and the errors from the application.
http://codebin.herokuapp.com?s=5f4436b6605a250004000001

edit for future readers: i fixed it by removing return from `return message.author.send`

Comment: The error means that `message.member` is undefined. Are you using the command in DMs?

Comment: yeah, i used it in the bots dms

Comment: That's why it's not working. `message.member` can't return a `GuildMember` object if you're not in the guild.

Comment: ohhhh thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make some verifications, when you use **return** the code stops there.

knowing that you can use if and verify if the user has admin.

```
if(!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("You can't use that command.");

//If the code doesn't stop in the if
//verification is because the user has administrator permission.

return message.reply("Hey, you are admin!");
```

Comment: This worked for like 10 minutes before breaking again :/

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the code that i send, probably you did some change that break the code.